# Обновление платформы битрикс, кодировка базы данных cp1251

Tags: mysql, битрикс, utf-8, cp1251

Нужен совет от опытных битрикс разработчиков. Есть сайт, у которого лицензия не продлевалась с 2015 года, версия платформы 14.5.0., php 5.6, база данных была создана в кодировке cp1251_general_ci

Не получается развернуть резервную копию не на open server, не на виртуальной машине. Я так подозреваю это из-за того что не совпадают конфиги на локальных серверах(open server) и на виртуальной машине (vmbitrix).

Вопрос такой как лучше поступить?

1. Нужно ли продлевать лицензию и обновлять платформу. Если да, то может ли поломаться сайт?
2. Можно ли поменять кодировку в бд на UTF-8, если да, то опять же не поломается ли сайт?

Сайт не большой не проще ли создать сайт заново в таком случае?

Comment: Есть скрипт от разработчиков битрикс https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/blogs/howto/1466.php для конвертации всего сайта в UTF8. Но работает он криво и у меня как раз и сломался сайт, когда пробовал. А при чем тут кодировка к тому, что сайт не разворачивается? Что именно там не разворачивается? Какая ошибка?

Comment: в open server просто пустая страница, а на виртуалке Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to 
Bitrix\Main\Diag\ExceptionHandler::handleException() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given in 
 /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/diag/exceptionhandler.php:167
Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: 
Bitrix\Main\Diag\ExceptionHandler->handleException(Object(Error))#1 {main} thrown in 
/home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/lib/diag/exceptionhandler.php on line 167

Comment: Это https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum32/topic103555/?PAGEN_1=9 не помогло?
"В меню машины пункт 1, потом 8 -> Rollback PHP to version 5.6"